# Balance of payments abbreviations

Tags: macroeconomics, national-accounts

I am trying to decipher certain abbreviations related to balance of payments. They are strange, and i have to admit i have no idea what did they mean furthermore i was not able to find anything relevant via google and also i am not able to find them in my macroeconomics textbook. So the abbreviations are:

rb, ka (capital account), rf, eo, bop (Balance of payments).

Those i know are in brackets. Could you help me find the meaning of those abbreviations?

EDIT: The question was the following given:
$rb=-1491, ka=2280, rf=-1551, rb+ka+eo=-3282$ calculate $bop$ and $eo$

answer is:
$eo=-4071$ and $bop=-1731$
and one more thing:
$rb+ka+eo-rf=bop$ and $rb+ka+eo-ka-rb=eo$ that is all i know.

Comment: You should probably include the equations they are in, otherwise they could stand for a lot of things.
Without the equations I would hazard a guess and say that $r_b$ might be the reserves the banks keep in the national bank and $r_f$ might be the reserve of foreign currency that the national bank holds.

Comment: I've added something, what about eo?

Comment: I don't know but this is merely an exercise. Any equations from the lecture part of the textbook?

Comment: The problem is that i am not able to find those abbreviations in both textbook and presentation from lecture, i've added two equations

Comment: EO = Errors and omissions

http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/metadata/en/bop_6_esms.htm